# Excel VBA- Data Cleaning- Date to string

Tags: excel, vba

I need to clean data tables to eventually create Bracket placements for NCAA Men's Basketball.  Unfortunately some of the data that I was given has transformed the record (i.e 10-20) to 20 Oct, whereas most other records remain in Win-Loss format (i.e. 20-10).  Could anyone offer any suggestions on how to transform the date formats (20 Oct) back to the intended win-loss format (10-20) for the worksheet on VBA?

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am new to this and must use VBA for this problem set.

Comment: Thanks a million! Just put it to work.

Answer (score 2):

Select the cells you wish to convert and run this short macro:

```
Sub fixdata()
    Dim v As Variant

    For Each r In Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Selection)
        v = r.Value
        If v <> "" And IsDate(v) Then
            r.Value = "'" & Day(v) & "-" & Month(v)
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Before:

[image]

and after:

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

Correction:

```
Sub fixdata()
    Dim v As Variant

    For Each r In Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Selection)
        v = r.Value
        If v <> "" And IsDate(v) Then
            r.Value = "'" & Month(v) & "-" & Day(v)
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Should the 20-Oct entry be converted to 10-20 instead of 20-10 and the 6-Apr entry to 4-6 instead of 6-4? From the question it sounds like Month-Day is required rather than Day-Month